# What docker images does DCOS Flink package require?

Tags: mesos, apache-flink, mesosphere, dcos

I have built a DCOS local universe and installed it into a cluster behind a firewall - there is no internet access to the cluster.  One of the packages installed in the universe is Flink.  I have installed DCOS using the `cluster_docker_registry_url` variable pointing at a local Docker registry which has a very small number of packages on it; it is not a mirror of the main Docker Hub.

When I try to install the Flink package into DCOS, I get 404 errors in the Mesos logs relating to missing docker images that I assume the package tries to download from the local Docker registry.  The Flink cluster fails to start.

What Docker images does the Flink package try to download?  I thought the build process of a local universe pulled all dependencies down when it is built, so there should be no external dependencies once it's built?  What do I need to do to be able to install DCOS when there is no internet access?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the scala version you are using:

- scala 2.10: `mesosphere/dcos-flink:1.2.0-1.4`
- scala 2.11: `mesosphere/dcos-flink-2-11:1.2.0-1.4`

See [here](https://github.com/mesosphere/universe/blob/4157d261a8bcb1ff745a861afd1818721a175b2b/repo/packages/F/flink/1/resource.json#L6-L7)

Furthermore, it requires

- openjdk:8-jre ,see [here](https://github.com/mesosphere/dcos-flink-service/blob/master/container/appmaster/conf/flink-conf.yaml#L31)

For more details feel free to refer to the universe specification for the Apache Flink service (or ping me directly):
https://github.com/mesosphere/universe/blob/version-3.x/repo/packages/F/flink/1/

Comment: P.S. The first two images change depending on the version of the framework (currently we are at 1.3.1), but at least so far the task image has been stable across versions.